# Integration Factor in terms of $x$ and $y$ used to reduce an ODE to an exact form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If your ODE is non exact you need an integrating factor to make it exact I'am asking for a general expression for finding this integrating factor

Let the Integration factor be  $T(x,y)$

$$T(x,y)M(x,y)dx +  T(x,y)N(x,y)dy  =0$$

Apply the  condition for exactness

$$ T_yM + M_yT = T_xN + N_xT   $$

Question is much easier if your T depends on x or y only

I want to ask how do solve the above PDE for the function T if it depends on both x and y

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking

Comment: if your ODE is non exact you need an integrating factor to make it exact  . After some inspection  your IF does not depend on x , it does not depend on y rather it depends on both x and y . I'am asking for a general expression for finding this integrating factor

Comment: There is no general method.

Comment: My lecturer ranked  3rd or 4th in Asia  says there is

Comment: if u have a question to solve  ho do you approach that

Comment: @TaimoorAli Yes, for bivariate Pfaffian form there's no general form of integrating factor. But if you impose some constraint, there it is. For example, if M and N are both homogeneous, then the integrating factor is $\frac1{Mx+Ny}$.

Comment: @TaimoorAli There should be some misunderstanding here on your side. There is a theorem that says that the integrating factor always exists (locally). And it is completely different matter to present a formula for it -- that does not happen often.

Comment: Then can u give any example .. how to solve one if IF depends on both x and y

Comment: @TaimoorAli See my answer. It also halps if you use @ name.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang  what do mean by   Bivariate Pfaffian form

Comment: @TaimoorAli I mean for $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$, there's no general integrating factor. You can refer to applications of Lie group in ODE to find integrating factor for different types of ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an integrating factor that depends both on $x$ and $y$. Since you have such a highly ranked lecturer, I will give this example by stating a problem:

> Let
>   $$
> M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0.\tag{1}
> $$
>   Show that if the expression
>   $$
> \frac{N'_x-M'_y}{xM-yN}
> $$
>   is a function of $xy$ only, then $(1)$ admits an integrating factor and find it.

Comment: Thank God this was the expression  i was looking for . Know after evaluating this expression ( and it comes out to be a function of x and y ) how do you use it to find the IF ...

Comment: let Integration Factor be F(x,y) then  F(x,y) = exp ( Integral of above Expression  ) . my question is   " with respect to what should I integrate your expression " e.g with dx dy or both .. Example can be helpful